# How to create mega menu in bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, blazor

I would like add a bring mega menu in our erp application. Can you share the link for the free bootstrap mega menu template. I have checked google but am unable to find the proper link.

Comment: just a sample for mega menu; https://bootstrap-menu.com/detail-megamenu.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, telerik isn't free (after 30 days) but you should be able to build your own based on this documentation.

https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/knowledge-base/menu-megamenu